# VS2010 Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting C# code for StackedChart

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, charts, data-visualization

Im creating a silverlight application for now, and I'm having a difficulty how to set an itemssource variable for a stacked chart.

Im using Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting library

I'm used to make a non-stacked chart like so

```
void getChartCompleted(object sender, GetChartCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Chart chart = new Chart();
            BarSeries barSeries = new BarSeries()
                {
                    ItemsSource = e.Result.Value,
                    DependentValueBinding = new Binding("Value"),
                    IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("Label")
                };
                chart.Series.Add(pieSeries);
            stackPanelChart.Children.Add(chart);
        }
```

Now, if I want it to be a stacked bar chart, how to set the 'e' variable? Also, what other setting should I appplied to the chart object?

Thanks